# unnecessary shift of cursor to console log

Tags: eclipse

I am using eclipse on Ubuntu. When there is log being shown in console and I am moving cursor up or down in JAVA file to see the code, the cursor shifts itself to the console log and and I am having problem to investigate my code. My cursor shifts to console log even if I disable the console view from windows-> Show View. Is there any way that I am not forced to see the console.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just got rid of this issue. Right click in console window, select preferences and then unchecked the checkBox "show when program writes to standard out" and also unchecked the checkBox "show when program writes to standard error".